# 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udf81' in position 7: surrogates not allowed- Email Export

Tags: pywin32, win32com

So I wrote a program that converts email files into a dataframe and then exports it into Excel through Outlook, however, I am having issues with a particular inbox that I believe has a non standard emoji in it that is breaking my Excel writer. I tried a few different versions of this I saw in the forums:

```
'\udf81'.encode('utf-16','surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')
```

However, I still get the issue about not being able to encode '\udf81'.

Here is my code:

```
import win32com.client as client
import pandas as pd
import time

start = time.perf_counter()

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')

account = namespace.Folders['gianfabian52@gmail.com']

inbox = account.Folders['Inbox']

all_inbox = inbox.Items

#test inbox
print(inbox.Name)
#test account is correct
print(inbox.Parent.Name)

#count inbox items to verify code collects all items
print(inbox.Items.Count)


#collect all emails in inbox
AllEM = [message for message in inbox.Items]

#create DF

dict = {'Subject': [],'Body':[],'Sender_Email':[],'Account':[]
        ,'Recieved_Time':[],'Classification':[]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)


#'Classification':[]

EM = [message for message in inbox.Items]
#message.SenderEmailType- determine email type and if in directory
#MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress - supposed to pull email from directory-issues
#message.SenderEmailAddress - pull SMTP email
def EmailDF():
    for message in EM:
            df.loc[len(df.index)] = [message.Subject, message.Body, message.SenderEmailAddress, account, message.ReceivedTime, 'NA']
        
EmailDF()
        
#remove timezone to avoid errors, and to keep clarity in pandas package 

df["Recieved_Time"]=df["Recieved_Time"].dt.tz_convert(None)

#sort by date and time
df = df.sort_values("Recieved_Time")

#print
print(df)

#writes out as csv without index
#csv
#df.to_csv('GianMail.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

#excel
df.to_excel("GianMail.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter', index=False)

finish = time.perf_counter()
print("Code executed in",round(finish-start,2),"seconds")
```